# Open all editors in the same window in netbeans

Tags: windows-7, netbeans, netbeans-7.2

In netbeans, all editors used to open in the same window. For example, if I double click a file in the project explorer, or double click a file from a search result, or from a subversion "show changes view", the new editor opens in the top right window.

Now, for some reason, the editors that I open from search results open in the search result window (that is, in the bottom right window and not the top right where all the other editors are).

How do I change the netbeans settings back so that every editor, no matter how I open them, show in the top right window ?

**Edit:** Netbeans behave as if I have this option activated: tools > options > windows > "New document opens next to active document tab". But if I uncheck it, nothing happens. All document still open next to active document tab. No changes if I restart the IDE.

Comment: also affects version 8.2, window/reset windows temporarily helps

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it is a bug in netbeans 7.1 or 7.2. https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=209468

Here is a quick fix: go to window / Reset Windows. Rearange your windows. The bug should disappear.

Comment: @pramod24 This type of comment is discouraged on StackExchange. But today i'm in a mannerly mood so screw the guideline: You're welcome